# KineticJS gives 2fps drag performance on Android mobile VS 20fps Android desktop

Tags: android, google-chrome, kineticjs

Very slow interactive drag performance (about 2 fps) while running a simple KineticJS version 5.0.2 app on Android Chrome (Android 4.3 on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition) BUT as soon as I select Chrome's setting to "Request desktop site" suddenly there's a massive performance increase of about 10x with the drag refresh rate. I'm not sure if this is a KineticJS issue or perhaps something else entirely. Running on a desktop browser on my workstation, performance is butter smooth.

Here's a description of the app: There's a bitmap in the background layer (900x600) and a PNG bitmap with alpha channel in the foreground layer (320x156) with draggable = true.

If I remove the background layer, then drag performance is OK.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now achieved a consistent frame rate of roughly 30 to 40 fps on both mobile and desktop modes on the Samsung tablet mentioned above!

The big change came from restructuring my game code which erroneously called init() several times (about 6 times) instead of just once, each time instantiating the stage and the multiple images.  I do also use "Kinetic.pixelRatio = 1" at the top of the code and a "Kinetic.FastLayer()" for my static background artwork.